# openvpn error: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, openvpn

I've got a problem on implementin openvpn So I'm here and hope some one could help me

the story:

I've installed openvpn server on a ubuntu server VPS and I've used the tun point-to-point instead of tap bridge.
there is no error caused by miss configuration on the server.

When I issue the openvpn client.conf command on the client, it gives me:

```
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 OpenVPN 2.1.0 i686-pc-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [PF_INET6] [eurephia] built on Jul 12 2010
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 /usr/bin/openssl-vulnkey -q -b 1024 -m <modulus omitted>
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 LZO compression initialized
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '69109d17'
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'c0103fa8'
Thu Oct 27 15:17:39 2011 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]VPS_IP_ADDR:4242 [nonblock]
Thu Oct 27 15:17:40 2011 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]VPS_IP_ADDR:PORT_NUM
Thu Oct 27 15:17:40 2011 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Thu Oct 27 15:17:40 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Thu Oct 27 15:17:40 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]VPS_IP_ADDR:4242
Thu Oct 27 15:17:40 2011 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]VPS_IP_ADDR:4242, sid=b78095e0 079e400c
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Thu Oct 27 15:18:40 2011 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

When I googled the problem I found out people and the openvpn manual itself are saying it's caused by the server's firewall configuration

here are my rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4242 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 4242 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to VPS_IP_ADDR
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your logs on a server side.
In my case TLS key negotiation error and user drops were due to OpenVPN Maximum client was achieved. I changed from 5 to 10 and works like a charm. Just check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

try to add cmd below in the *.ovpn config file:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

And open openvpn using the cmd:

```
openvpn --cd /Path/to/your/configs --config *.ovpn
```

Answer (score 0):

This error cleared after uncommenting the **TLS-Auth** key in Client Conf {ovpn} file, and validating the server **ta.key**

Comment: how exactly do you validate the ta.key? going through a very similar issue

Comment: Sorry for being that much late, you simply trace the  error log, for me the issue was related to NTP was not fixed correctly, so always giving expired ta.key